# Tensorflow seq2seq Decoder problems?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, translation

I try to write a seq2seq decoder with the tensorflow tf.contrib.seq2seq package. 
I am wondering if my code is correct and if there is better way to rewrite it. The documentation is not easy to read.

Or my question can be: how can I easily debug this kind of code? How can I inspect some intermediate results in tensorflow?

```
class Decoder:
    def __init__(self, embedding, hidden_size, num_layers=1, max_length=15):
        self.embedding = embedding
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden_size)  
        self.linear = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(self.hidden_size, cn_total_words))*0.1)


    def __call__(self, inputs, state, encoder_outputs, encoder_state, decoder_length, mode="train"):


        with tf.variable_scope("decoder") as scope:

            inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embedding, inputs)
            encoder_state = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(encoder_state, 1), (1, tf.shape(inputs)[1], 1))

            attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention(self.hidden_size, encoder_outputs)
            attn_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(self.cell, attention_mechanism, self.hidden_size)
            if mode == "train":
                helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs=inputs, sequence_length=decoder_length)
            elif mode == "infer":
                helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(embedding=self.embedding, 
                                                start_tokens=tf.tile([en_dict["BOS"]], [tf.shape(inputs)[0]]), end_token=en_dict["EOS"])

            decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=attn_cell, helper=helper, 
                                                      initial_state=attn_cell.zero_state(tf.shape(inputs)[0], tf.float32))

            outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=decoder)
            outputs = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(out, 1) for out in outputs], 1)

            outputs = tf.tensordot(outputs, self.linear, axes=[[2], [0]])
            return outputs, state
```

I got the following error when running the code

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       434                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype,
>   --> 435                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
>       436             if input_arg.number_attr and len(
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in internal_convert_n_to_tensor(values, dtype, name, as_ref,
>   preferred_dtype)
>       736             as_ref=as_ref,
>   --> 737             preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype))
>       738   return ret
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref,
>   preferred_dtype)
>       675         if ret is None:
>   --> 676           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>       677
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
>       548         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r"
>   --> 549         % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
>       550   return t
>
> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with
>   dtype int32: 'Tensor("seq2seq-train/decoder/ExpandDims_2:0", shape=(?,
>   1, ?), dtype=int32)'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 emb_en = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1, size=(en_total_words, hidden_size))
>         5 emb_cn = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1, size=(cn_total_words, hidden_size))
>   ----> 6 model = Seq2Seq(hidden_size, num_layers, emb_en, emb_cn)
>         7 sess = tf.Session()
>         8 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
>
> in **init**(self, hidden_size,
>   num_layers, embed_words_en, embed_words_cn)
>        81             encoder_outputs, encoder_state = self.encoder(self.encoder_inputs, self.encoder_length)
>        82             decoder_length = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(self.decoder_mask, 1), tf.int32)
>   ---> 83             decoder_outputs, decoder_state = self.decoder(self.decoder_inputs, encoder_state, encoder_outputs,
>   encoder_state, decoder_length)
>        84 
>        85             # decoder_outputs.append(decoder_out)
>
> in **call**(self, inputs, state,
>   encoder_outputs, encoder_state, decoder_length, mode)
>        50 
>        51             outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=decoder)
>   ---> 52             outputs = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(out, 1) for out in outputs], 1)
>        53 
>        54             outputs = tf.tensordot(outputs, self.linear, axes=[[2], [0]])
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py
>   in concat(values, axis, name)    1064   return
>   gen_array_ops._concat_v2(values=values,    1065
>   axis=axis,
>   -> 1066                                   name=name)    1067     1068
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py
>   in _concat_v2(values, axis, name)
>       491   """
>       492   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis,
>   --> 493                                 name=name)
>       494   return result
>       495
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       461                                 (prefix, dtype.name))
>       462               else:
>   --> 463                 raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
>       464             else:
>       465               raise TypeError("%s that are invalid." % prefix)
>
> TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have
>   types [float32, int32] that don't all match.